# The Doom of us all

Tags: riddle, language

### **ᚱᚨᚷᚾᚨᚱᛟᚲ**

*The battle grounds are soaked in sweat

Blood red embers stain the sky

The father of the beasts is dead

Flickering flames dance farewell,

Like a swan, red as blood.*

---

The war is over.
My father is dead.
My brother is dead.
Finally, I can return.

**What is my name?**

Answer (score 3):

> The answer is the norse God Baldr,
> The elder futhark at the top spells ragnarök and the first text says flickering flames dance farewell which i think refers to sutr destroying the 9 worlds to ash.
> but The god baldr was killed before ragnarok and sent to hellheim(the realm of the death) that is the reason why he is one of the sole surviving gods of ragnarok. the last sentence is finally i can return which led me to thinking its Baldr/Baldur

Comment: Nice! You've got the right name, but you haven't explained the most important part of the riddle (the top half), so I can't accept this answer just yet

Comment: im grabbing my edda. give me some time haha

Answer (score 2):

> I believe the answer is **Hela** (Daughter of Odin and sister of Thor). The runes at the top say 'Ragnarok' which I believe is a reference to the film 'Thor: Ragnarok'. Hela knows that Odin is dead and believes Thor and Loki are dead too (her brothers) so she finally can return to Asgard.

Comment: Also a great guess :) the answer could indeed be Hela if you're only using the runes and the bottom half of the riddle, but the first five lines should reveal the true name